# Após edição o layout na área da pergunta fica maior que o esperado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design, layout

Vejam este exemplo:

<kbd>[image: quebra layout pergunta]</kbd>

- [Como fazer slides verticais de página inteira que rolem com o scroll do mouse?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109420/3635)

A principio achei que era a área de fechamento, mas usando o Inspetor de elementos eu fui deletando todos "Nodes html" até encontrar o problema.

Ele só ocorre quando existe uma edição de outra pessoa, se olhar outras perguntas verá que o problema não ocorre.

O problema ocorre devido a dois fatores

1. O primeiro e mais importante é o uso de tabelas para marcação e divisão do layout:

   <kbd>[image: tabelas]</kbd>

   Quando o espaço da celula na tabela excede ele aumenta a tabela conforme necessário, no caso o espaço horizontal excedeu e naturalmente a tabela ampliou a largura (que é o comportamento esperado das tabelas).

   Eu vou dizer logo de cara (algo que já citei aqui) usar tabelas pra dividir layout é algo que pode ocasionar muitas dores de cabeça e eu sei que parte do layout ainda foi mantido como era em 2008 (quando a primeira comunidade foi criada), mas acho que usar tabelas além de mais difícil de fazer manutenção ainda é necessário escrever muito mais. Tabelas tem esse comportamento de se autoajustar a largura e altura pois é para trabalhar com dados tabulares (semelhante a planilhas).
2. Antes usava-se tabelas e o problema não ocorria, **eu não tenho certeza**, mas o motivo me parece que moveram os links *compartilhar, editar, reabrir, remover, sinalizar* e *proteger* para dentro da do `<tr>` aonde se encontra a área de edição (eu não tenho certeza se sempre esteve dentro deste `<tr>`, mas se me recordo antes eles ficavam abaixo).

---

### Soluções possíveis

Não vou ficar aqui falando pra pararem de usar tabelas para dividir o layout, mas acho que seria um bom começo. Todavia trocar a posição do links *compartilhar, editar, reabrir, remover, sinalizar* e *proteger* já resolveria o problema, fazendo algo como:

```
<table class="fw">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" class="post-signature">
                <div class="user-info ">
                    <div class="user-action-time">
                        <a href="/posts/109420/revisions" title="mostrar todas as edições desta publicação">editada <span title="2016-01-24 05:32:37Z" class="relativetime">24/01 às 5:32</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-gravatar32">
                        <a href="/users/201/brasofilo">
                            <div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXJw1.png?s=32&amp;g=1" alt="" width="32" height="32"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-details">
                        <a href="/users/201/brasofilo">brasofilo</a>
                        <div class="-flair">
                            <span class="reputation-score" title="pontos de reputação " dir="ltr">4.491</span><span title="4 medalhas de ouro"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">4</span></span><span title="16 medalhas de prata"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">16</span></span><span title="43 medalhas de bronze"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">43</span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="post-signature owner">
                <div class="user-info ">
                    <div class="user-action-time">
                        perguntada <span title="2016-01-20 20:43:33Z" class="relativetime">20/01 às 20:43</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-gravatar32">
                        <a href="/users/27321/natcorsi">
                            <div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rOz8cKO64dk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAT3o/jcS65ToGHbw/photo.jpg?sz=32" alt="" width="32" height="32"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-details">
                        <a href="/users/27321/natcorsi">NatCorsi</a>
                        <div class="-flair">
                            <span class="reputation-score" title="pontos de reputação " dir="ltr">13</span><span title="2 medalhas de bronze"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">2</span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="vt">
                <div class="post-menu"><a href="/q/109420/3635" title="permalink curto para esta pergunta" class="short-link" id="link-post-109420">compartilhar</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/109420/edit" class="edit-post" title="analise e melhore esta publicação">editar</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="#" class="close-question-link" title="votar para reabrir esta pergunta (quando reaberta, novas respostas poderão ser adicionadas novamente)" data-questionid="109420" data-isclosed="true">reabrir</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="#" id="delete-post-109420" title="votar para remover este post" class="" data-delete-prompt="Votar para remover este post? (10 votos restantes)" data-undelete-prompt="Restaurar o post? (faltam 10 votos)">remover</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="#" class="flag-post-link" title="sinalizar esta publicação por problemas sérios ou para atenção do moderador" data-postid="109420">sinalizar</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a id="protect-post-109420" href="#" title="proibir respostas de usuários anônimos e muito novos de baixa reputação">proteger</a></div>
                <script>
                    StackExchange.using("inlineTagEditing", function () {
                        StackExchange.inlineTagEditing.init();
                    });
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

E no CSS adicionar um `float: right`:

```
.user-info {
    float: right;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px 6px 7px 7px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #52575c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O programador do site deve saber resolver isso com os olhos vendados, mas deixo uma sugestão para resolver sem mexer muito no que existe.

Na tabela:

```
<table class="fw">
....
</table>
```

Remover essa coluna

```
<td align="right" class="post-signature">
[aqui dentro tem a div com os avatares]
</td>
```

A div com os avatares empurra para baixo da tabela.

```
<br clear="all" />
<div class="user-info user-hover">
...
</div>
```

Na classe `user-info`, certificar-se de que tem o `float:right;`.